# Does an object instance keep the same memory address

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following code

```
  foo* f = new foo();
  std::cout << static_cast<void*>(f); //0xcf1c20
```

now in the above code `f` pointer points to the address `0xcf1c20`. This is the address of `foo` instance. My question is suppose  the above instance residing on the address `0xcf1c20` does not get deleted will the instance always live on this memory address through out the life of this application ? Or are there case in which the same instance might be placed on a different memory address ?

Comment: Yes it does because there is normally no garbage collector that might relocate object.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Could you put that down as the answer

Comment: Not really, because I can't really prove it, we should find a reference to standard, I am sure it is covered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one particular object will have that same address for as long as it exists, yes. Objects do not move around in memory unless you move them yourself (or do so indirectly: for example, elements of a standard container being moved due to your manipulation of the container).

Provided that you are fully aware of all such occasions, **you may safely use an object's address as its identity.**

That doesn't mean that other `foo`'s will have the same or even a similar address, even if created by the same code (say, in a function or loop). Just that one object created at that specific point in time.

Comment: I am wondering is it fixed in standard or this is just assumed as a fact of life.

Comment: @Andrey: I think it's required but not explicitly stated. The standard takes the inverse approach, defining objects as regions of storage and by virtue of that definition requiring that "one object" <=> "one region of storage". Then by deduction one cannot change w.r.t. the other. It's not "can we prove that an object cannot move in memory" it's "an object _is_ a position/range in memory!"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you mentioned (or do so indirectly: for example, elements of a standard container being moved due to your manipulation of the container). Could you explain that ? or give a simple example ?

Comment: @JamesFranco: Do you know how `std::vector` works? If not, read that particular chapter in your C++ book then come back to let me know.

Comment: @JamesFranco _"Objects do not move around in memory unless you move them yourself"_ — This formulation is strongly misleading. Objects themselves cannot be moved; each object has the same region of storage during its entire lifetime. Only their **content** can be moved, whatever this means (such as some allocated resources, file handles, etc.). Vectors do not move objects at all, they need to construct new elements (by copy/move constructors) and then destruct the original ones. Yes, we usually say that "objects are moved", but when you care about storage/addresses this is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the address with remain the same throughout the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 0):

In case of JAVA we can't free object on our own as in java we have garbage collector which take care of freeing the object which have no reference also known as dead objects ,but in c we have that provision so the answer to your question is yes.